# Silent boot opensuse without fbsplash

Tags: terminal, boot, opensuse

I want to boot my openSUSE 10.3 distro without any boot messages.

I've looked at fbsplash, but it requires patching the kernel, a thing which I cannot do at the moment (not because I don't want it or that I don't know how to do it, but because we are working with running linux distributions all over the world, which can't be reinstalled).

So I went on trying to disable as much console output as possible by editing the `menu.lst` file for grub and some other things. That partially worked but several kernel errors keep popping up. I just want to boot up silent until the terminal login screen. Is this possible?

Comment: Opensuse uses bootsplash by default

Comment: It could be hard to eliminate all outputs, why wouldn't you try to fix the `error`?